# how to return false if two div have the same value when submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form has a lot of selects inside divs so i want when the user submits the form if there are two div or more have the 
same value, form example the first has this value : 1 one and the third has 
the same value so don't submit and return false, so is there any way javascript or jquery can help me to do that?

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
   alert("2 div or more have the same value, please change them");
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
      <select class="number">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
     <select class="letter">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
     </select>
 </div>
  <div>
      <select class="number">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
     <select class="letter">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
     </select>
  </div>

  <div>
     <select class="number">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
     <select class="letter">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
     </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what you have to do is to validate your form field before complete the request, there must be a lot of JS libraries available, however you have to validate the same in server side.

Comment: I don't have time to add a full answer, but I would look into jquery's "each" method, and combine that with the "number" and "letter" classes you already have as the selectors.  I would also use preventDefault() instead of return false.

Comment: - Pavul Zavala thank you brother but i need to your full answer when you can i will wait you and thanks in advence

Comment: So look at all the values and see if you have a duplicate. Seems straight forward, what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this javascript code keeping your html

```
$("form").submit(function(event)
{
   var selects = $('select');
   selects.each(function(i,select1){        
   var found = false;
      selects.each(function(j,select2){         
           if(i!=j && select1.value == select2.value){
               alert("2 div or more have the same value, please change them");
               found = true;
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
       });
       if(found){
           return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: _Iriam Gonzalez_ thatks but it did not  work..i want that the result in the first line are not the same in the second or third or auther line.. for exmple i don't like to get this result  1 one ... 1 one --> i like this result 1 one 1 two...or 1 one 2 one......